# Move xml nodes between parents and delete duplicates - xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, duplicates, xslt-2.0

I have an xml as follows and would like to 1) move values in the Data node to Header if the match the attribute name or 2) delete nodes under Data if the name attribute is the same as an existing node in the header using xsl tranform, if possible.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Initial xml:

```
<HEADER>
   <KEY name="child1" value="value1" />
   <KEY name="child2" value="value2" />
   <KEY name="child3" value="value3" />
   <KEY name="child4" value="value4" />
</HEADER>
<DATA>
   <KEY name="child1" value="value1.data" />
   <KEY name="child3" value="value3.data" />
   <KEY name="child5" value="value5" />
   <KEY name="child7" value="value7" />
</DATA>
```

If Child 5 is the node to move, the result is...After Transform:

```
<HEADER>
   <KEY name="child1" value="value1" />
   <KEY name="child2" value="value2" />
   <KEY name="child3" value="value3" />
   <KEY name="child4" value="value4" />
   <KEY name="child5" value="value5" />
</HEADER>
<DATA>
   <KEY name="child7" value="value7" />
</DATA>
```

current xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <!-- <xsl:variable name="ReplaceLiveDate" select="false()" /> -->
    <xsl:variable name="ReplaceLiveDate" select="true()" />

    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

    <!-- base identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- in HEADER: output ROLE sorted by @name -->
    <xsl:template match="HEADER">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="KEY">
                <xsl:sort select="translate(@name, $smallcase, $uppercase)" order="ascending" />
                <!-- <xsl:sort select="@name" /> -->
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- in DATA: output KEY sorted by @name -->
    <xsl:template match="DATA">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="KEY">
                <xsl:sort select="translate(@name, $smallcase, $uppercase)" order="ascending" />
                <!-- <xsl:sort select="@name" /> -->
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

I have the following to remove nodes, but unsure how to only do it if the node exist in the header section

```
<!-- remove processing nodes -->
<xsl:template match="KEY[starts-with(@name, 'child1')]"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to do that transformation, but in this case i think that the smart one is to use the xslt **keys feature** see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_key.asp) for a brief description

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <!-- <xsl:variable name="ReplaceLiveDate" select="false()" /> -->
    <xsl:variable name="ReplaceLiveDate" select="true()" />

    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

    <!-- index all the KEY element of the HEADER -->
    <xsl:key name='head' match='HEADER/KEY' use='@name' />


    <!-- base identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match='HEADER'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <!--  move the child5 'KEY element' under the header  -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="//DATA/KEY[@name = 'child5']"/>
            <!--  apply to childs   -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="KEY">
                <xsl:sort select="translate(@name, $smallcase, $uppercase)" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- delete key nodes duplicated in Header, that is elments not indexed by the 'head' key -->
    <xsl:template match="DATA/KEY[key('head',@name)]">
    </xsl:template>

    <!--  delete the node to be moved -->
    <xsl:template match="DATA/KEY[@name = 'child5']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For simplicity the stylesheet above won't sort the header keys in alphabethical order, if you really need it, then a [perform-sort](http://www.xmlplease.com/xmltraining/xslt-by-example/xslt-by-example.html#perform-sort) is necessary.

I tried to keep much as possible of your original stylesheet, but I didn't  find out any other solution following that way.

Below the template if you want key sorted by the @name attribute

```
<xsl:template match='HEADER'>

    <xsl:variable name='unsorted_keys'>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//DATA/KEY[@name = 'child5']"/>
        <!--  apply to childs   -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="KEY">
        </xsl:apply-templates>          
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:copy>      
        <!--  make sure to copy HEADER attributes  -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select='@*'/>

        <!--  perform sort  -->
        <xsl:perform-sort select="$unsorted_keys/KEY">
            <xsl:sort select="translate(@name, $smallcase, $uppercase)" order="ascending" />
        </xsl:perform-sort>         
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  I now have the move and delete functions working, but I am unclear on the perform-sort function.  Do I need to simply wrap my sort statements in a perform-sort node?  Do I put this at the end?  Are variables needed as shown in the examples?

Additionally, would it be better to put all my sort in this perform-sort format?

Comment: Yes, you could use perform-sort link in the example perform-sort_1-stylesheet.xsl. Just store the _generated_ nodes in a variable, do perform-sort, the emit sorted nodes with the `<xsl:copy-of />` instruction

Comment: I finally got the sort to work, but I noticed that I am getting duplicates in the header section if the node already exist.  Should I wrap each xsl:copy-of statement in an if statement?  This is the issue with child1 and child2 in the original example.

Comment: so you want remove **both** nodes (in Header and Data section) if they are there ?

Comment: I believe the issue is if the same node is in the HEADER and DATA sections, it is not removed with the template match for the 'head' values.  ie...<KEY name="child1" value="value1" /> in both HEADER and DATA sections